# How to use chrome dev tools to view http requests sent by javascript

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, browser, request

I'm relatively new to coding and something that I've noticed recently is that when I load onto a website, there are some cookies that I receive that do not show up in the chrome dev tools networks tab. An example of such is the google analytics cookies. When loading onto a website, I searched through all the requests shown in chrome dev tools and was not able to see a single request that returned the cookies. Because of this, I assumed that there were requests being sent through javascript in the browser. Is there any way I can view these requests in chrome dev tools or in any other browser/software

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are sent in the "Set-Cookie" headers of a network response.  You can see them in the network tab if you click on one of these requests and look in the "Headers" pane for "Response Headers":

[image: Chrome Network tab showing Set-Cookie response header on a request]

You can also see them more easily in the "Applications" tab, under "Cookies" section:

[image: Chrome Application tab showing cookies]

Answer (score 1):

`Right click` -> `inspect` -> then you will have the chrome dev tools just by selecting `networks` you can filter what's the browser is loading also you can see the `http` request going through your application.
[image]

I recommnad also that you check this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)